# Help prompt for "Experience" section is not in a helpful position

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

For example;

> [image]

Chrome, Windows 8. I assume either;

1. The help tip should be aligned slightly less to the right of the input boxes
2. The unicorn you were planning to insert in the space has ran away.

> [image]

... I hope it was the latter.

Comment: -1 needs more freehand circles and waffles `</joke>`

Comment: @Doorknob: Jeez, meta's becoming a tough crowd... there's unicorns in there!

Comment: Confirmed. Trying to find that unicorn now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed.

We're also tweaking our JavaScript to dynamically make space for the unicorn, should it ever decide to come back...

Comment: Shouldn't this be [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: Yepp. Done and done.